# how to make dynamic result if checked some radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, radio-button

```
<script type="text/javascript>
     $("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function() {
         var val = this.value;
         var dataSplit = val.split("_");
         if (this.checked) {
            var result = '<div id="div'+dataSplit[0]+'"><input type="radio" class="choosen" name="rdb" value="'+val+'" id="'+dataSplit[0]+'" /><label class="'+dataSplit[0]+'">'+dataSplit[1]+'</label><br /></div>';
            $("#resultrdb").append(result);
         }else{
             $('#div'+dataSplit[0]).remove();
         }
    });

    $("#btnsubmitIndustry").click(function(){
         var n = $(".choosen").length;
         var valPrimary = $(".choosen:checked").val();
         var valSecondary = $(".choosen:not(:checked)").val();
         var data='<ul>';
         data += '<li>Primary = '+valPrimary+'</li><li>Secondary:'+valSecondary+'</li>';
         data += '</ul>';

         $("#result").html(data);
     });    ​
</script>
```

here i can get 1 value of unchecked radio, then how can i get another unchecked value of radio button ? i want to make the result dynamic, i think i should use looping ? example : if there are 3 radio, and 1 clicked, i want to show primary(the clicked radio value),secondary, and third data in the result

thx

FIDDLE = http://jsfiddle.net/F3muF/8/

Comment: can you show us _before_ and _after_ form elements?

Comment: @Raminson its exactly like on the fiddle

Comment: I'm lost. *What* are you trying to do? Show examples! If your fiddle works, why do you need help?

Comment: i want a dynamic results
example : i click 3 checkbox, it will show 3 radio button, and when i click submit, the result will be the value of the clicked button and 2 value from unclicked button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = '<ul><li>' + $('.choosen:checked').val() + '</li>';

$('.choosen:not(:checked)').each(function () {
  data += '<li>' + $(this).val() + '</li>';
});

data += '</ul>';

$("#result").html(data);
```